# Добавить кнопку сворачивания и разворачивания

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с использованием JQuery добавить кнопку сворачивания и разворачивания таблицы на пятой строке? При этом кнопка должна появляться при количестве строк больше восьми.

Comment: А проблема в чём?

Comment: Как выразить это условие jquery?

Comment: Какое это? У Вас же ничего не подготовлено для решения Вашей задачи, а нумерация, в целом, ни при чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, смысл, думаю, ясен, допилите сами:

```js
let trL = $('tr').length;
let trW = +$('tr:first-child').css('height').replace(/\D/g, '');
let wrapper = $('#wrapper');

if (trL > 8) {
  wrapper.css({
    'height': trW * 5 + 'px'
  });
  let sh = $('#sh');
  
  sh.on('click', function (e) {
    if($(this).text() === 'Show') {
      $(this).text('Hide');
      wrapper.animate({
        height: trW * trL + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      $(this).text('Show');
      wrapper.animate({
        height: trW * 5 + 'px'
      });
    }
  });
  
  sh.css({display: 'block'});
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sh {
  width: 90%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>#1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id='sh'>Show</div>
```